# how can i change the old google map dependency to new one?

Tags: android-studio, localization, geolocation

i need little help i develop with a guy at 2017. it was working properly but now its not working beacause of Map api issue i need to fix this i searched it alot but i am not getting any solution please help me any body

when i am storing my address its not working i created new api in could google

i used these dependency

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
```

and in minifest

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

how it will work properly again thanks